# Mongostat locked db field

Tags: mongodb

Can someone explain which DB is represented by "." in locked db field in mongostat output mean? Does it mean global lock? Also its being output every 2 seconds, any specific reason why its happening every 2 seconds? Is it something to do with replication happening within the replica set?

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults        locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn    set repl       time
*0     *0     58     *0     191    63|0       0  4.39g  9.02g   241m    376       local:0.5%          0       0|0     0|0    28k    66k    55 rs-lol  PRI   11:28:21
*0     *0     25     *0      93    30|0       0  4.39g  9.02g   241m    335       local:0.7%          0       0|0     0|0    13k    34k    55 rs-lol  PRI   11:28:22
*0     *0     19     *0      49    26|0       1  4.39g  9.02g   241m    150          .:23.1%          0       0|0     0|0     9k    27k    55 rs-lol  PRI   11:28:23
*0     *0     20     *0      67    25|0       0  4.39g  9.02g   241m    139       local:0.2%          0       0|0     0|0    10k    28k    55 rs-lol  PRI   11:28:24
*0     *0     28     *0     102    30|0       0  4.39g  9.02g   241m    392       local:0.7%          0       0|0     0|0    14k    37k    55 rs-lol  PRI   11:28:25
*0     *0     38     *0     133    41|0       0  4.39g  9.02g   241m    424       local:0.9%          0       0|0     0|0    19k    46k    55 rs-lol  PRI   11:28:26
*0     *0     40     *0     144    45|0       0  4.39g  9.02g   241m    284       local:0.4%          0       0|0     0|0    20k    49k    55 rs-lol  PRI   11:28:27
*0     *0     39     *0     138    43|0       0  4.39g  9.02g   241m    333       local:0.7%          0       0|0     0|0    19k    48k    55 rs-lol  PRI   11:28:28
*0     *0     44     *0     159    49|0       0  4.39g  9.02g   241m    522       local:0.8%          0       0|0     0|0    22k    53k    55 rs-lol  PRI   11:28:29
*0     *0     35     *0     128    37|0       0  4.39g  9.02g   241m    391       local:0.7%          0       0|0     0|0    17k    43k    55 rs-lol  PRI   11:28:30
```

Comment: global lock, as to why it is happening, hmmm, not sure, what quieries do you have?

Comment: What member did you do this on as well?

Answer (score 0):

The locked db field you are referring to in your example now refers to the per DB locks as of version 2.2. Prior to version 2.2, it referred to global write locks.